# SQL Server dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables and I want to return result as one dynamic table, and use it with an ASP.NET `GridView`. However when I run my query I get a syntax error:

```
Declare @AghlamTitle_Topic nvarchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select 
    @AghlamTitle_Topic = 
          stuff((select distinct ','+QuoteName([TopicTitle]) 
                 from Tbl_Topic 
                 where Topic_PID = 29 
                 for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') 

Set @Query = ' Select * 
               From (Select  
                         t2.Aghlam_Marasemat_PID,
                         View_Marasem_ALL.MarasemID ,
                         t2.[AghlamDateReg], 
                         t1.[TopicTitle], 
                         t2.AghlamCount  
                     from 
                         Tbl_Aghlam_Num t2 View_Marasem_ALL 
                     inner join 
                         Tbl_Topic t1 
                     pivot (max([AghlamCount]) for [TopicTitle] in ( ' +@AghlamTitle_Topic + ' ) ) p 
                inner join t2 on View_Marasem_ALL.MarasemID = t2.Aghlam_Marasemat_PID'

exec sp_executeSql @query
```

Does someone have a solution?
[image: screen]

Comment: Is t2 a table??? in your @query you just mentioned to join with t2. I think you are missing table name there.

Comment: Short version - your query is a mess. Long version - 
I'm guessing that `View_Marasem_ALL` should not be a part of the from clause. Also, you are using aliases in the outer queries that belongs to the inner queries, and not providing any join condition for the derived table.

Comment: yes t2 is table.
t1 is Tbl_Topic table.
if remove View_Marasem_ALL its return Tbl_Topic join t2
but i need join with View_Marasem_ALL too

Answer (score -1):

`Tbl_Aghlam_Num t2 View_Marasem_ALL`

This is a syntax error.   You have a Table name followed by the alias name `t2` followed by `View_Marasem_ALL`, whatever that is.

If you need to also join to `View_Marasem_ALL`, then you need to add an additional JOIN clause.

Comment: "then you need to add an additional JOIN clause"
I JOIN View_Marasem_ALL in '@Query' but its return syntax error.

Comment: Edit your question and post the new query that has the syntax error.